# How to change routing in bitnami?

Tags: php, linux, apache, bitnami

I have two custom php apps in bitnami. First one in `apps/site` and second in `apps/forum`. How can I make it so the site loads when you go to `domain.com` and forum when you go to `forum.domain.com`?

Now to access those two apps I need to go to `domain.com/site` and `domain.com/forum`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitnami Engineer here,

If you are using the default paths, follow these steps (they use `/opt/bitnami` as installdir and `pwd`):

- Add the file `site/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf` with the content below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/site/htdocs"
    Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/site/conf/httpd-app.conf"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/site/htdocs"
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.key"
    Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/site/conf/httpd-app.conf"
</VirtualHost>
```

- Add the file `forum/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf` with the content below:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName forum.domain.com
    ServerAlias www.forum.domain.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/forum/htdocs"

    Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/forum/conf/httpd-app.conf"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName forum.domain.com
    ServerAlias www.forum.domain.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/forum/htdocs"
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.key"

    Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/forum/conf/httpd-app.conf"
</VirtualHost>
```

- Comment out these lines from `apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf`:

```
#Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/site/conf/httpd-prefix.conf"
#Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/forum/conf/httpd-prefix.conf"
```

- Add these lines to `apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-vhosts.conf`:

```
Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/site/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf"
Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/forum/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf"
```

- Restart apache.

I hope it helps

Comment: Well I did like you told me but when I get 403 Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Comment: It is difficult without knowing how your apps are configured. The main reasons of this error are:
 * Incorrect file or folder permissions
 * Incorrect settings in the .htaccess file
Note that Bitnami configuration disables `.htaccess` files due to security and performance reasons.
I think this 2 links to our documentation could help:
https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/infrastructure/lamp/administration/create-custom-application-php/
https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/infrastructure/lamp/configuration/configure-custom-application/

Comment: I fixed it by adding
`
<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/site/htdocs" >
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
    </Directory>
`